# How can I reverse the output stream in c++?

Tags: c++

What I am trying to achieve is to use the standard std::cout and if you understand, reverse the output to an input so another part of my program can read it. No I cannot just call a function in the other part of my program because every function is and must stay private so this seems the only way to do it. I did a similar thing in java by redirecting the default output stream to my own custom one but I am somewhat new to c++. This is what I did in java:

```
System.setOut(customPrintStream);
```

Does anyone know of an alternative for c++ or a way to get whatever is printed to console?

Comment: If you already have the line when you print it out to the console, why do you need to read it back from the console? Are you trying to see if it has changed your string somehow?

Comment: Its not the point that I already have the string I need everything from my program that is printed not just my code but errors and such

Comment: why is this being down voted

Comment: How about your output goes to a socket then the other guy can read from the socket. Seems not too hard to do.

Comment: @Marichyasana Creating a server would be extremely messing and not practical in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The c++ standard library supports the concept of 'reverse iterators'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    auto s = std::string("Hello, World");
    std::copy(std::rbegin(s), std::rend(s),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
dlroW ,olleH
```

Comment: No you misunderstood me i don't want to reverse whatever i print to it. i want whatever i print to be read by another part of my program

Answer (score 0):

The streams in C++ read from and write to `std::streambuf` objects. You can replace the stream buffer of an `std::ostream` object using the `rdbuf()` function. For example, to capture all output written to `std::cout` in a `std::string` you could use something like this:

```
 std::ostreamstream stream;
 std::streambuf*    sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(stream.rdbuf());
 // use code whose output is written to `std::cout`
 std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf); // restore the original stream buffer
 std::string output = stream.str();
```

In a real implementation you'd probably use an RAII approach to replace/restore the stream buffer. Also, you might want to use a custom stream buffer rather than a `std::stringbuf` but the basic remain as is.

Comment: So this would just need to be added to a loop to work?

Comment: @Hamish: it depends on what you want to do with the data. You could use the captured strings in a loop, for example. You could also create a custom stream buffer which calls a registered function, e.g., when the stream is flushed or a specific character is encountered. The key part this shows is redirecting a stream elsewhere. The next step is to decide how to use the data.